# Align Select boxes and text boxes

Tags: html, css, select

[image: Drop down select boxes]

This is what my front end currently looks like. I am trying to figure out how to get the drop down boxes to align to the right with each other. So they will all match with the one that is furthest out.

ID
                        
        Equals
        Less Than
        Less Than or Equal To
        ">Greater Than
        =">Greater Than or Equal To

This is what one of the elements look like in HTML.

Comment: use a hidden table and place the elements in that

Comment: can you provide some markup, or css you have so far?

Comment: need your html code without that its hard to find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put each inside a div with a width, say 90%, then float each box to the right.

Comment: @TroyReynolds Great! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

For a dynamic solution without setting widths you will need to use 2 wrapper containers.

Btw I don't agree with the other commenters advising to use tables for layout, that's a big no-no. Tables should be used for data, not positioning.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>another example</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <select name="foo" id="foo">
      <option value="foo">foo</option>
    </select>
  </li>
    <li>
    <select name="bar" id="bar">
      <option value="bar">bar</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden table and place the elements in that. You can add CSS to it as needed.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>abc</td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```